# LibGDX Json parser - parse specific node/object

Tags: java, json, parsing, libgdx

I'm currently implementing JSON parsing in my game but I've encountered a problem that I can't find a solution for: how do you parse a specific node/object (not sure what to call it) from a JSON file? Let's say my JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "intro/credits": { //A node/object.
        "title": "Intro music / Credits music",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Vindsvept",
                "links": {
                    "YouTube": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfSUheoljDlGDjerRylO4Nw",
                    "Bandcamp": "https://vindsvept.bandcamp.com/"
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    "extra": { //Another node/object.
        "title": "extra",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "extra",
                "links": {
                    "linkTest": "linkTest"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With that JSON in mind, how would I do something like this?:

```
MyObject myObj = json.fromJson(parse.object.called.extra);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the LibGDX Tutorial that tells you exactly what your asking? [LibGDX Reading & writing JSON](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON), Section Marked: Reading Object Graphs, is what your looking for.

Comment: @Underbalanced Oh, sorry. I read that earlier and I must've skimmed over the part about JsonValue, not realizing what it really was and that it can be used to represent the json DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Underbalanced](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6341307/underbalanced) I can now answer my own question: to exctract an object called `extra` you would do something like this:

```
Json json = new Json();
JsonValue root = new JsonReader().parse(Gdx.files.internal("path/to/your/file.json"));
JsonValue extra = root.get("extra"); //Replace 'extra' with whatever your object is called.
MyObject myObj = json.fromJson(MyObject.class, extra.toString());
```